# LDAP password hash matching in Java

Tags: java, authentication, hash, passwords, ldap

I have this kind of password hashes in my LDAP database:

```
userPassword:: MTIzYVBkLSY=
```

I'm also caching the users password hash in my application so it is not needed to enter it every time. Given this, I want to check if a DN exists with the specified password. What kind of hash algorithm is this? Can I produce the same type of hash in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is `base64` encoding. [try it here](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/)

Comment: This does not answer the question. He wants to know the hashing. Since the hash is very short, this cannot be a hash. Not even MD5.

Comment: Actually it did answer my question, I just found the attributeType in the schema file, and it is defined as an `OctetString`.

Comment: An `OctetString` is not a concrete data definition. It just means that it can contain any _transparent 8-bit bytes_. Hence it contains any binary data.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a password hash, that seems to be the password, encoded in Base64 format.

If you decode the posted string the you get the password `123aPd-&`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if a DN exists with the specified password.

The way to do that is to perform an LDAP `bind` with that DN and password as the credentials. In JNDI this is done via `LdapContext.reconnect()`.

> What kind of hash algorithm is this?

It doesn't matter, you don't need to know.